# Simulation doubt with Zener diode & MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, current, simulation, zener, nmos

I have the below circuit in which I am trying to perform simulations.

Simulation Tool used - [Falstad Simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/)

[12V Zener Diode](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BZX84_SER.pdf)

[Top MOSFET](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NVMFS5C670NL-D.PDF)

[Bottom MOSFET](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK7Y3R5-40E.pdf)

Question 1 :

[image]

The Zener diode is 12V Rated.

I want to simulate a current of 12A through both the MOSFETs

So, for my 16V input voltage, I calculated my Resistance to be 1.33Ohms to get a current of 12A.
But when both the MOSFETs are ON, my drain current through them is only 91mA. Can someone tell me what is the problem and why am I not getting a drain current of 12A? And I tried to change the Rds(on) MOSFET parameter in the tool, but not able to find and change it.

Next Question :

[image]

When I apply a negative voltage of -14V to the gate of the bottom MOSFET as shown below, I get a voltage at the Zener cathode as 2.195 and a voltage between the MOSFET nodes as 2.7V with 6.4mA of current?

Can someone tell me how this 2.195V and 2.7V is appearing? Just want to understand the circuit behaviour in these conditions. Please help.

Comment: Can someone help me with the understanding of the circuit during these conditions?

Comment: 1- wrong simulation model. 2 - The upper MOSFET (T1) is ON and the lower (T2) could also be ON or be on the edge of turning ON. Because the Zener diode is forward biased (0.6V), thus the voltage at the T1 source (T2 drain) is 5V - Vgs = 2.7V. And the voltage at the T2 gate is 2.7V -0.6V = 2.1V. So this voltage at the T2 gate could turn T2 ON.

Comment: @G36, thank you for the analysis. I am not able to get on why you did - "5V-Vgs = 2.7V" Also, I would like to understand what is wrong with the simulation model in (1).  Please explain me how you arrived at 5V-Vgs = 2.7V and how is the 2.7V voltage arrived in the simulation too? Please help in simple terms. Have been stuck at this place for long time.

Comment: Show us the link to the simulation.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y9r67vsk

Comment: @G36,  please use the above link which I have used for the simulation

Comment: For what I can see you set Vgs(th) = 1.5V and beta = 20m. But from the datasheet  https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK7Y3R5-40E.pdf  we can see that (fig 6) beta = 0.5* 25A/(5V - 1.5V)^2 = 1 So you shoud be generous ( make good switch) and set the beta value = 20.

Comment: For the situation two (Vin -14V) we have this situation 5V - Vgs1 - Vd - Vgs2 = 0 thus if MOSFET are identical (Vgs1 = Vgs2) and we assume that Vd = 0.6V, we have Vgs = (5V - 0.6V)/2 = 2.2V and the voltage at T2 drain is Vgs + Vd = 2.2V + 0.6V = 2.8V

Comment: Can you explain to me the purpose of the upper MOSFET and the Zener diode? And what these resistors ( 82k, 18k) do at the upper MOSFET drain?

Comment: The Upper MOSFET is driven by an enable signal from the MCU and the resistors act as a resistor divider and this output voltage is fed to the ADC pin of the microcontroller. Zener diode is to hold the voltage at a maximum of 12V if the value exceeds more than 12V. The voltage range at the gate of the bottom MOSFET is 9-16V. And since it is a battery terminal, reverse voltage is also applicable. Reverse voltage is -14V

Comment: @G36, thank you. But I am really failing to understand the Voltage you have calculated. Could you please draw a Loop and help with the KVL and arrive at that voltage please. Could you please consolidate your comments into an answer for the benefit of all

Comment: @G36, could you please explain the voltages with the help of KVL and provide with an answer for the benefit of all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-**
From your [simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Af+256+144+336+144+32+1.5+0.02%0Af+256+304+336+304+32+1.5+0.02%0A34+fwdrop%5Cq0.8+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+0+1.9189505033+12%0Az+224+240+224+304+2+fwdrop%5Cq0.8%0Aw+336+288+336+240+0%0Aw+256+240+336+240+0%0Aw+336+208+336+160+3%0Aw+224+304+208+304+0%0Ar+144+304+208+304+0+10000%0AR+144+304+80+304+0+0+40+-16+0+0+0.5%0AR+144+96+64+96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+144+96+144+144+0+1000%0Ar+144+160+144+208+0+100000%0Aw+224+208+336+208+0%0Aw+144+144+224+144+0%0Aw+144+144+144+160+0%0Aw+336+96+336+128+0%0Aw+336+128+400+128+0%0Ar+400+128+464+128+0+82000%0Ar+464+128+464+176+0+17800%0Ag+464+176+464+208+0%0Ag+336+320+336+384+0%0Aw+144+208+224+208+0%0Ag+512+192+512+224+0%0AR+272+64+112+64+0+0+40+16+0+0+0.5%0Ar+272+64+336+64+0+1.33%0Ac+224+144+224+208+0+1e-9+2.305301082142804%0Aw+224+144+256+144+0%0Aw+336+208+336+240+0%0Aw+224+240+256+240+0%0Aw+224+304+256+304+0%0Ac+512+128+512+192+0+1e-9+2.852130976220311%0Aw+336+64+336+96+0%0Aw+464+128+512+128+0%0A), I can see that you decided to use wrong MOSFET parameter.

\$V_T = 1.5V\$ and \$\beta = 20 \text{m}\:A/V^2 \$

And this, for example, will give us the drain current for \$V_{GS} = 4.5V\$ equal to:

$$I_D = \frac{\beta}{2}(V_{GS} - V_T)^2 = 90 \text{mA} $$

Therefore you need to increase the \$\beta\$ value.

We can calculate the needed \$\beta\$ value by using this approximate equation (MOSFET in Triode region)

$$\beta = \frac{1}{R_{DS(ON)}(V_{GS} - V_T)}$$

For example for \$V_T = 1.5V\$, \$V_{GS} = 10V\$,\$ R_{DS(ON)} = 30\text{m}\Omega \$

$$\beta = \frac{1}{R_{DS(ON)}(V_{GS} - V_T)} = \frac{1}{30\text{m}\Omega(10V - 1.5V)} \approx 4 \:A/V^2$$

Thus to fix your simulation you need to increase the \$\beta\$ value.

> When I apply a negative voltage of -14V to the gate of the bottom
> MOSFET as shown below, I get a voltage at the Zener cathode as 2.195
> and a voltage between the MOSFET nodes as 2.7V with 6.4mA of current?
>
> Can someone tell me how this 2.195V and 2.7V is appearing? Just want
> to understand the circuit behaviour in these conditions. Please help.

Hmm...strange circuit.

The upper MOSFET will be ON because the gate of the upper MOSFET is at \$+5V\$.
So the current will continue to flow through the forward-biased Zener diode and into the lower MOSFET gate resistor. And if the MOSFET threshold voltage is low (as is in your case) the lower MOSFET will also be ON.

We can apply KVL here and see what we get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJQWXQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_G=V_{GS1}+V_D+V_{GS2}$$

And in your simulation, we have perfectly matched MOSFET's (Id1 = Id2 ignoring diode current, thus Vgs1 = Vgs2 )

$$V_{GS} = \frac{V_G - V_D}{2} = \frac{5V - 0.6V}{2} = 2.2V$$

And the voltage at the \$T_2\$ drain will be \$V_{D2} = V_{GS}+V_D = 2.8V\$

\$I_{D2} = \frac{\beta}{2}(V_{GS} - V_T)^2 = \frac{20\text{m}}{2}(2.2V - 1.5V)^2 = 4.9\text{mA}\$

\$I_{D1} = I_{D2} + I_{DZ} = 4.9\text{mA} + \frac{2.2V+14V}{10k\Omega} = 6.5\text{mA}\$

And I must say that I don't like this circuit at all.

Why the Zener diode is connected between the gate and the drain of a lower MOSFET?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The Zener diode can be connected between the gate and drain, right? Like, if the Lower MOSFET is turned ON, the Zener diode is between the supply and the ground only. That's why

Comment: But why you want to "protect" the gate and the drain terminals?

Comment: I want to protect them because, the absolute maximum ratings of gate to source voltage of the MOSFET is 20V. So, I am protecting it with a zener diode so that the maximum voltage of the gate to source voltage of the MOSFET does not exceed the Zener breakdown voltage which is not more than 12V